# Custom callout view with button over a MKMapview in iOS 3.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I created a subclass of `MKAnnotationView` which when selected display a callout view (similar to the MKPinAnnotationView) which is just a subclass of `UIView` with a button and text for now. The callout is added to the annotation view. The problem i have is that the button i put in the callout view never trigger any action, it does not seem to respond to touch event.

The reason i create a new `MKAnnotationView` is because i need to display more
than text and two buttons in the annotation view and i could not find a way
to achieve this with the regular `MKPinAnnotationView` callouts.

Code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation:(id ) annotation {
    if(![annotation isKindOfClass:[CSMapAnnotation class]])
        return nil;

    CSMapAnnotation* csAnnotation = (CSMapAnnotation*)annotation;

    CustomAnnotation *customAnnotationView=[[[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
    MKPinAnnotationView* pin = nil; pin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:customAnnotationView reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"] autorelease];
    [pin setPinColor: MKPinAnnotationColorRed ];
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = pin;

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    [pin setPinColor:(csAnnotation.annotationType == CSMapAnnotationTypeStart) ? MKPinAnnotationColorGreen : ((csAnnotation.annotationType == CSMapAnnotationTypeCarLocation)? MKPinAnnotationColorPurple:MKPinAnnotationColorRed) ];



    UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,85,25)];
    [leftView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UIButton *shareButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [shareButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [shareButton setFrame:CGRectMake(19+GAP, 0, 25, 25)];
    [shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(shareButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [leftView addSubview:shareButton];


    UIButton *setAlertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [setAlertButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alert.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [setAlertButton setFrame:CGRectMake(shareButton.frame.origin.x+shareButton.frame.size.width+GAP, 0, 25, 25)];
    [setAlertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(alertButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [leftView addSubview:setAlertButton];


    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = leftView;
    [leftView release];

    return annotationView;
}

-(void)shareButtonAction:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"%s",_cmd);
}
```

**The shareButtonAction action is not calling when I am clicking the shareButton...**

---

I checked above delegate also but It is not called when installed to iPhone 3.0.. This delegate will call if i have only one button to right callout but (In the above case)it is not calling when adding view with two buttons. Its happening in iPhone 3.0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241340/how-to-add-custom-view-in-maps-annotations-callouts

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are aware (or if you care) but you are passing an MKAnnotationView to a method that asks for MKAnnotation and this is bound to cause you problems later down the track.

Also because of that, I don't know if my answer will actually work for you but there is a delegate method that gels called when you tap the callout's accessory control. After setting yourself as the mapview instance delegate, simply implement:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
   NSLog (@"Callout accessory control tapped");
}
```

Comment: I checked above delegate also but It is not called when installed to iPhone 3.0.. This delegate will call if i have only one button to right callout but (In the above case)it is not calling when adding view with two buttons. Its happening in iPhone 3.0...

Comment: So it's not going to work by using a MKViewAnnotation - you will need to create a custom UIView, put it on top of the map and capture the touches.