# How To add custom View in map's Annotation's Callout's

Tags: iphone, maps

Here is my code. I want to add my own custom callout view instead of iOS default. I know there is only left callout and right callout view, but I need to add a view tooltip type with my own background and label.

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
    {
        MKAnnotationView *userAnnotationView = nil;
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:MKUserLocation.class])
        {
            userAnnotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"UserLocation"];
            if (userAnnotationView == nil)  {
            userAnnotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"UserLocation"];
            }
            else
                userAnnotationView.annotation = annotation;

            userAnnotationView.enabled = YES;


            userAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            userAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_pin.png"];
            UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,141,108)];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toltip.png"]];
            [view addSubview:imgView];
            userAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = view;



            return userAnnotationView;
        }

}
```

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814988/mkmapview-instead-of-annotation-pin-a-custom-view

Comment: https://github.com/okhanokbay/MapViewPlus

Answer (score 133):

I had same problem and ended up doing following thing:

When I receive mapView delegate callback

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

(it's time when I want to show my custom CalloutView)

I use view received as parameter ***(MKAnnotationView *)view***  (which is a pin view) and simply add my custom view to that pin view using

```
 [view addSubview:customView];
```

It will add your custom view on top of that pin view so if we want it to be above pin we have to change custom view center property like this:

```
CGRect customViewRect = customView.frame;
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(-customViewRect.size.width/2, -customViewRect.size.height-7, customViewRect.size.width, customViewRect.size.height);
        customView.frame = rect;
[view addSubview:customView];
```

In my case it looks like this

[image]

**!NOTE**:

There is one caveat which however can be easily fixed, your ***custom view will ignore touch events***, because of **mapView** working with touches differently. Here's a ***quick fix***:

**1)** Subclass **MKAnnotationView** (or **MKPinAnnotationView** depends on what you need)

**2)** in your mapView delegate

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

use your subclass instead of MKAnnotationView/MKPinAnnotationView

**3)** in your subclass .m file override two methods as following:

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UIView* hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView != nil)
    {
        [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    }
    return hitView;
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;
    BOOL isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point);
    if(!isInside)
    {
        for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
        {
            isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point);
            if(isInside)
                break;
        }
    }
    return isInside;
}
```

**All done!**

Comment: what is visibleCalloutView ?

Comment: Dunno if there are any better ways of doing this, but one year later, this solution works amazingly well! Thanks for the additions on working out the touch issues with the custom view. Cheers!

Comment: Regarding touch issues, the touch works, but didDeselectAnnotationView still gets called and it dismisses the callout. Do you have the same? Is there a more elegant solution than flagging the 'touched' annotation view to save its state and prevent deselection?

Comment: @ChristopheFondacci is didDeselectAnnotationView get called when you touch annotationView or customView, that you added?

Comment: @haawa deselect called when I touch the custom view. I managed to get the custom view receive the hit, but it is as if the event is propagated to the underlying map. For example, I can drag the map while touching and holding on the custom view, or if I tap my custom view and there is another annotation behind, this other annotation is selected. I got the impression that whenever the tap is outside the annotation view bounds, you could manage to receive the hit, but can't avoid the map to process it as well

Comment: just wanted to add that to make this view disappear on button click, add MKMapView and id<MKAnnotation> as properties of this custom view and call **[self.mapView deselectAnnotation:self.annotation animated:YES];**. MKAnnotation is a property of MKAnnotationView.

Comment: @amcastror not sure why, but you need to have a UIButton as the control that receives the touch outside annotation bounds and override hitTest in the AnnotationView to check for hits in subviews (something like this answer but I recursively hitTest subview). When UIButton receives the hit, it works (but it is slow), without UIButton the touch reaches the map but it is very fast... I think there is a bug somewhere in MapKit

Comment: Hi haawa, can you please share your custome view code, i am new to mapkit, it will save me alot thanks!

Comment: addSubview:customView.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width*0.5f, -self.visibleCalloutView.bounds.size.height*0.5f);   In this method "visibleCalloutView " which object repesents, i m getting error "not found on object type ", please help me.

Comment: did you guys managed to do it? I have the same problem here and I don't understand what "you need to have a UIButton as the control that receives the touch outside annotation bounds and override hitTest in the AnnotationView to check for hits in subviews" means

Comment: @Gamer this shows erroe, did you find any solution? addSubview:customView.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width*0.5f, -self.visibleCalloutView.bounds.size.height*0.5f);

Comment: Awesome post! I think visibleCalloutView is the customView in the example from @haawa.

Comment: @haawa - Salute you boss, save my life can you please elaborate more why  MKAnnotationView ignore touches ?

Comment: @iPatel it is because the added subview is out of superview's visible rect. if you set `clipsToBounds` on `MKAnnotationView`, you can't even see the added subview. From iOS9, there is a `detailCalloutAccessoryView` to customize callout.

Comment: What is VisibleCallOutView??

Comment: I'm confused here - adding the subview will add your custom view **below** the callout? How can you move your custom view above the callout? OR in reference to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766219/remove-mkannotationview-default-callout-from-view

Answer (score 10):

I have created a library to show custom callouts.

[DXCustomCallout-ObjC](https://github.com/s3lvin/DXCustomCallout-ObjC)

You can pass any custom view for the callout! 
It supports events for UIControls as well.

[image: Custom Callout]

Comment: Just used it on iOS 9 and seems fine so far.

Comment: Hi, how do I hide your callout when another annotation is selected ?

Comment: @Misha a callout should hide automatically when another one is selected. There seems to be some issue with this behaviour when callouts are too close/overlapping. I will try to fix and push an update when I get some time.

Comment: I hoped the same. But it isn't working. callouts are not closing . :(

Answer (score 2):

**To the best answer above in Swift**

This can save some minutes to rewrite itself.

!NOTE:

There is one caveat which however can be easily fixed, your custom view will ignore touch events, because of mapView working with touches differently. Here's a quick fix:

1) Subclass MKAnnotationView (or MKPinAnnotationView depends on what you need)

2) in your mapView delegate

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
```

use your subclass instead of MKAnnotationView/MKPinAnnotationView

3) in your subclass .m file override two methods as following:

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    let hitView = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)

    if (hitView != nil)
    {
        self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)
    }

    return hitView;

}

override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

    let rect = self.bounds
    var isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point)

    if(!isInside) {
        for view in self.subviews {

            isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point)
            break;
        }
    }

    return isInside
}
```

Comment: i think your break should be put in a if isInside {}

Answer (score 1):

Here is Best Example of CallOut View

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/gikanimatedcallout

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/multirowcalloutannotationview

Answer (score 1):

I just created a custom callout for my map view which avoids issues with the callout disappearing when tapped. [Here](https://gist.github.com/ShadoFlameX/7495098) is a Gist with the steps I took.

Comment: I had implemented your code, but its not working. can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library. It also provides a ready-to-use template for the callout view. Adds cool animations and an anchor view for your custom views.

https://github.com/okhanokbay/MapViewPlus

[image] [image]