# Troubles with MKViewAnnotation frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have trouble with MKAnnotationView Frame. Before asking I want to clarify some things.

First:

I have a `MKMapView` and some custom annotation:
[image]

It looks ok.

Second I draw a Line via `MKPolylineView` between user's location and this custom annotation:

[image]

Looks pretty good

Third, Then I tried to change default annotation image by my own custom:

[image]

Right here we have wrong result, coz annotation not not connected with line

Forth, Okey I tried to change position of this image:

[image]

I just added to `MKAnnotationView` a new `UIView` with my `UIImageView`.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = nil;
    annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pin"];

    if(!annotationView)
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:person reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];
    else
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;



    UIImageView *avatarImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 25, 25)];
    avatarImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:avatarName];

    [annotationView setImage:nil];

    avatarImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    UIView *avatarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-7, 23, 30, 30)];
    avatarImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    avatarView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;


     [avatarView addSubview:avatarImage];
     [annotationView addSubview:avatarView];

     return annotationView;
}
```

After all:

[image]

This is What I want :)

But sometimes when I tap this annotation `didSelectAnnotationView:` isn't called. I know why, coz my `UIView` with my image out of `MKAnnotation`.

I changed background color of `MKAnnotation`:

[image]

When I tap this red region `didSelectAnnotationView:` is called.

SO, question is how can I change frame of this `MKAnnotationView` so that my `UIView` will not be outside?

P.S. I tried change frame, doesn't work :D

P.S.S Sorry for my English :(

Comment: Are you looking for `centerOffset` property of `MKAnnotationView`?

Comment: @Desdenova Yeah, but this doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem. 
I just replaced `MKPinAnnotationView` with `MKAnnotationView`, and I get what I need.

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
                annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pin"];

                if(!annotationView)
                    annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:person reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];
                else
                    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

                /*
                 Avatar Image
                 */
                annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;

                [annotationView setImage:[self image:[UIImage imageNamed:avatarName] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(25, 25)]]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a long explanation on custom callout view here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19404994/1226370.

All details about touch handling are described in linked answer.

Hope it will be useful!

**Update 1**

After you will subclass your MKAnnotationView or MKPinAnnotationView you will implement two methods as follows:

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UIView* hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView != nil)
    {
        [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    }
    return hitView;
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;
    BOOL isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point);
    if(!isInside)
    {
        for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
        {
            isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point);
            if(isInside)
                break;
        }
    }
    return isInside;
}
```

In short, in those methods you specify whether touch at current location should be treated as touch on MKAnnotationView or not.

So if you want to increase touch area of annotation you would have to make proper changes to those methods.

Comment: But, how can I change frame/region where we can tap? In your solution, I guess, you make that if you tap subview of this annotation view the method hintTest returns YES. So my problem solved partially :)