# MKMapView calloutview height

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, mkmapview

I want to increase height of calloutview but i tried lot of code but still height is not increasing ,
Please tell me how can i increase calloutbubble height

I am using this code

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";
MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
if (annotationView == nil)
{
    annotationView =[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
}


NSLog(@"array count %lu ",(unsigned long)[arrayOfAnnotation count]);

if ([arrayOfAnnotation containsObject:annotation])
{
    for (OSAnnotation *anootation in arrayOfAnnotation)
    {
        if (anootation==annotation)
        {
            //NSLog(@"UserName : %@ ",model.fullName);
            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinGold24.png"];
            annotationView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,32,32);
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            annotationView.draggable=NO;
            annotationView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

            //   NSLog(@"latitude = %f logintude = %f",lati,longi);

            UIView *calloutView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100)];
            UIImageView *imgListingImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 60)];
            imgListingImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            UILabel *lbl_title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 10, 200, 21)];
            lbl_title.text = map_title;
            [lbl_title setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
            [calloutView addSubview:lbl_title];
            [calloutView addSubview:imgListingImage];


            annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView=calloutView;
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    annotationView.canShowCallout=YES;
    annotationView.draggable=NO;
    annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinGold24.png"];
}

return annotationView;
}
```

my calloutview is looking like this

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241340/how-to-add-custom-view-in-maps-annotations-callouts might be helpful to you.

Comment: try with a bigger callout image (bigger annotation view image)