# ios Custom annotation view using storyboard in MapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkannotationview, custom-view, query-by-example

I'm trying to add a custom annotation view in mapkit . When I tap on red annotation pin , I got an annotation callout,but it is very simple.I want to add a custom view which I have made in the storyboard.
Can you please provide me a video or text tutorial link or any other kind of help  regarding the same.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{

    if([view isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]){

        return ;
    }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D optimusInfoCallOut = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.625551, 77.373268);

    [self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(optimusInfoCallOut, 800, 800)animated:YES];

    UIImageView *imgView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loc.png"]];

    CGRect calloutViewFrame = imgView.frame;
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(calloutViewFrame.size.width/8.0, calloutViewFrame.size.height-24, 200, 100);

    CustomPointAnnotation *cpa = [[CustomPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    cpa.name = @"OpTi";
    cpa.imgName1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loc.png"]];
    self.customCallOutDetailsView.name.text = cpa.name;
    self.customCallOutDetailsView.callImage = cpa.imgName1;

    [self.view addSubview:self.customCallOutDetailsView];
}
```

My customCallOutDetailView is showing on tapping the annotation,but it's not showing at that annotation pin point, i think the view is taking its coordinates from the origin of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this method you can add you custom view.

```
  -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{

 [view addSubview:customView];
}
```

More information on the following link : 
[How To add custom View in map's Annotation's Callout's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241340/how-to-add-custom-view-in-maps-annotations-callouts)

Comment: I can't see the custom call out at pin point location.It is showing at the right corner of the map.
can you help me regarding that ?I've posted my code also.

Comment: customView.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width*0.5f, -self.visibleCalloutView.bounds.size.height*0.5f);

Comment: Thanks a lot doing fine now... :)

Comment: The link was really helpful.