# Remove MKAnnotationView Default Callout From View

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am trying to ***prevent*** `MKMapKit` from presenting the default annotation callout when tapping on a marker displayed on a `MKMapView` ***without*** blocking the delegate call / interaction of the annotation (seen below).

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotation:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    // Custom callout initialized & presented here
    . . .

}
```

I understand you may disable the callout from showing entirely

```
someAnnotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
```

or (more of a hackish approach) **not** setting any display parameters of the annotation:

```
// Commenting out string assignments below

// someAnnotation.title = @"Hey!";
// someAnnotation.subTitle = @"Aren't I an annoying callout :P ?";
```

As suggested in other threads, adding a subview to the annotation view *does* indeed add a custom view (whatever you please) to a bounding frame of your choice.

**THE ISSUES**, however, are that adding a subview

1. Does **not** stop the default callout bubble from appearing
2. **IF** you disable `canShowCallout` **OR** don't set the labels, annotation interaction is lost..
3. **IF** you add a subview, it gets added **below** the default callout.

**3 NOTE**
You can delay the addition of your subview by +0.5 seconds, which then will add your custom view **above** the callout, but this is a poor workaround as you see the default callout come into view well before yours..

Is there any workaround for either

1. Removing the default callout **without** disabling the delegate method from being called,
2. or Editing the actual callout view (I'm guessing it's some `CGPath` or `UIBezierePath` drawn view)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Update:**

I am using the delegate `mapView:viewForAnnotation` to create and add annotation views to my map.

Comment: Are you implementing `viewFor annotation:`? I've only taken a cursory look at MapKit, but *"The annotation view to display for the specified annotation or nil if you want to display a standard annotation view."* looks like that's what you want ... https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview

Comment: @DonMag yes - taking advance (perhaps not the most advantageous way for my case) of the `viewFor` method to handle adding annotations. Not sure how to go from here in still allowing touch interactions

Comment: Ah... a little more investigating (for *my* information)... Seems `viewFor annotation` is the view that shows on the map - such as a "Pin" image. The "callout view" is what shows when you tap the "Pin". This SO question may be helpful...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241340/how-to-add-custom-view-in-maps-annotations-callouts/19404994#19404994

Comment: Right. Looks like the setAnnotation method can help override drawing / setting the callout. More specifically with the post you reference (one I viewed already) http://stackoverflow.com/a/29594428/4577249 this helped point me in the right direction in setting a completely custom callout

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

**Register your custom MKAnnotationView**

```
mapView.register(AnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
```

**if you don't return your annotationView from this delegate method it will show default callout bubble when you tap on it**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    guard let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier) else { return .init() }
    return annotationView
}
```

I had same problem and this solution works for me

Answer (score -1):

When selected remove both title and subtitle of the annotation:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        if let annotation = view.annotation {
            annotation.title = nil
            annotation.subtitle = nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cannot assign to property: 'title' is a get-only property,
Cannot assign to property: 'subtitle' is a get-only property